# Windows doesn't use the Mac's full screen

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, display

I have installed Windows 7 on my Mac. Now when I run Windows 7, it displays in a 7 inch screen only, not full screen. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using bootcamp, the first place I'd look would be the video card drivers - and I wouldn't bother with the ones Apple supplies for either an ATI or Nvidia card. Grab the official drivers from the appropriate site.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you installed it, but, if you installed it via virtualisation, make sure the "tools" or similar are installed from the virtualisation package you use.

It sounds like you simply have to change the screen resolution (or just install the tools).

To change the resolution without installing tools:

Right click on an empty part of the desktop and choose "Screen Resolution".

Then simply change the resolution.
[image]